# Positioning a children div depending on screen size and parent div position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div (which is a basically a button) that shows another div (which is basically a container for some items).

Check real world example:

[image]

And a [working example in Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPvfSJ8IngeFFGAcHvMd).

As you can see, the container layer is placed below the button with

```
position: absolute;
```

which works fine if the button is somewhere in the upper left corner of the page, but not that fine if the button is somewhere on the bottom or somewhere on the right side of the page, as it's always shown below the button and expanded to the right. That causes the layer to be rendered outside of the webpage visible area and creates scrolls.

Is there any way I could do the following only with CSS:

- if there is no enough space o the right, render the layer by placing the upper right corner of the layer to the lower right corner of the button.
- if there is no enough space on the bottom, render the layer by placing it on top of the button.

Note that I don't know previously neither the width or the height of the layer.

This can be a HTML5/CSS3 solution, I don't need to support old browsers.

Comment: CSS can't detect your layout and space for elements...so I'd be thinking JS would be the answer here.

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought after 15 years and a next-gen CSS standart this would be finally possible without JS :(

Comment: Oh dear me no...CSS can't detect anything, it's unlikely it ever will..it styles based on selectors and applies rules accordingly.

Comment: well, You **are** using angular, so who not implement check, on open and add class to container if needed? to put container to top, You can do transformation. Example to top: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUHQN2GqCvv5PrH7H7W3?p=preview)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Yeah, I'm ware I can do it with JS. I was looking for a pure-css solution because I don't want to bload my code with visual-related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK is not possible. The possible way is detect it with javascript or if you only want to use CSS you must define the position classes. Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown btm-right">
  <span class="button">Button</span>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="item">Item</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
}
.dropdown:hover .items {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown.btm-right {
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown.top-right {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown .items {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown.btm-right .items {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
}
.dropdown.top-right .items {
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
```

Then we can use the `btm-right` or `top-right` class to position the dropdown. Thanks!